# Is there a way i can get this dropdown list to be shown when you hover over the list itself?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-grid

If I weren't using grid to make the topnav, I would just make a div and put item 2, 3, 4 and 5 in there so they appear when you hover over the div and stay like that even if you hover over the list itself. I have tried to implement such a div in the grid but unfortunately I couldn't make it work. Thanks in advance :).

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
}
#Topnav1{
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: plum;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 1fr / repeat(23,1fr);
    grid-gap: 0px;
    order: 1;
    z-index: 3;
    grid-template-areas: 
    " a a a a a a a b b b f f f g g g h h h h h h h "
    " . . . . . . . c c c . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
    " . . . . . . . d d d . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
    " . . . . . . . e e e . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
    ;
    font: 20px Arial black, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;
}
.topgrid{
    border: 1px black solid;
    background-color: darkblue;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
}
#Topnav1 a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.topitem2:hover ~ .topgrid{
    display: flex;
}
.topitem1{grid-area: a;}
.topitem2{grid-area: b;}
.topitem3{display: none; grid-area: c;}
.topitem4{display: none; grid-area: d;}
.topitem5{display: none; grid-area: e;}
.topitem6{grid-area: f;}
.topitem7{grid-area: g;}
.topitem8{grid-area: h;}
img{
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav id="Topnav1">
        <div class="topgrid topitem1"><a href="#"><img src="../Images/logo.png"></a></div>
        <a href="#" class="topgrid topitem2">item 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="topgrid topitem3">item 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="topgrid topitem4">item 4</a>
        <a href="#" class="topgrid topitem5">item 5</a>
        <a href="#" class="topgrid topitem6">item 6</a>
        <a href="#" class="topgrid topitem7">item 7</a>
        <div class="topgrid topitem8">
            <form id="frm1">
                <input id="text" type="text" name="searchbox" placeholder="Search here...">
                <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: I honestly think this can be made in a simpler way. You overcomplicated yourself too much.

Comment: @MarkBurns You're right. In fact, I have created something like this with flexbox already. It's just that I just started learning grid and I couldn't figure this particular problem out. So basically it's just for learning purposes.

Comment: Yes to Markburns, try to use GRID only for the Layout, not for the elements in the grid. for example use a simple nav, with nested submenu, and show or hide with the over of the parent li element of the Nested UL

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Example of this

https://codepen.io/r0binxp/pen/JjXXvEm

the grid only used for a layout. and the submenu, nested in the list item

```
#Topnav1{
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: plum;
    display: grid;
    order: 1;
    z-index: 3;
    font: 20px Arial black, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 3fr 1fr;
}
```